# Python - Change variable outside function without return

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and I ran into this problem. I want to set a variable from inside a function, but the variable is outside the function.

The function gets activated by a button. Then I want to get the value from that variable that I set when I press another button. The problem is that the value that I put inside a variable from inside the function doesn't stay. How would I solve this?

The code is underneath. `currentMovie` is the variable I try to change. When I press the button with the function `update_text()`, it prints out a random number like it is supposed to. But when I press the button that activates `update_watched()` it prints out 0. So I am assuming the variable never gets set.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

current_movie = 0

def update_text():
    current_movie = random.randint(0, 100)
    print(current_movie)

def update_watched():
    print(current_movie)

root = Tk()
root.title("MovieSelector9000")
root.geometry("900x600")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
canvas = Canvas(app, width = 300, height = 75)
canvas.pack(side = "left")
button1 = Button(canvas, text = "SetRandomMovie", command = update_text)
button2 = Button(canvas, text = "GetRandomMovie", command = update_watched)
button1.pack(anchor = NW, side = "left")
button2.pack(anchor = NW, side = "left")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple (python 2.x) example of how to 1 *not* use globals and 2 use a (simplistic) domain model class.

The point is: you should first design your domain model independently from your user interface, then write the user interface code calling on your domain model. In this case your UI is a Tkinter GUI, but the same domain model should be able to work with a command line UI, a web UI or whatever.

NB : for python 3.x, replace `Tkinter` with `tkinter` (lowercase) and you can get rid of the `object` base class for `Model`.

```
import random
from Tkinter import *


class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_movie = 0

    def update_current_movie(self):
        self.current_movie = random.randint(0, 100)
        print(self.current_movie)

    def update_watched(self):
        print(self.current_movie)

    def example_with_args(self, arg):
        print("ExampleWithArg({})".format(arg))


def main():
    model = Model()
    root = Tk()
    root.title("MovieSelector9000")
    root.geometry("900x600")
    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid()
    canvas = Canvas(app, width = 300, height = 75)
    canvas.pack(side = "left")
    button1 = Button(canvas, text = "SetRandomMovie", command=model.update_current_movie)
    button2 = Button(canvas, text = "GetRandomMovie", command=model.update_watched)
    button3 = Button(canvas, text = "ExampleWithArg", command=lambda: model.example_with_args("foo"))
    button1.pack(anchor = NW, side = "left")
    button2.pack(anchor = NW, side = "left")
    button3.pack(anchor = NW, side = "left")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: suppose, i need the value of updated currentMovie in my main function. How should I proceed then? Since I can't use return?

Comment: @bobthebuilder you just use `model.currentMovie`, why ?

Comment: My currentMovie variable doesn't get updated by the class functions for some reason. I wasn't finding any answers, so I had to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 9):

Use `global` to modify a variable outside of the function:

```
def update_text():
    global current_movie
    current_movie= random.randint(0, 100)
    print(current_movie)
```

However, don't use `global`. It's generally a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Thanks, I could't understand why until I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Comment: What should I use instead of global?

Comment: @MikeOttink In this case it's a bit of a rough spot, as `tkinter` demands a function to update your variable. You can encapsulate your state in a class, but in this case solving it with a `global` isn't the worst thing. If you have a lot of state though you should generally encapsulate it.

Comment: To tell someone the only solution is to use `global`, and then give the advice not to use `global` isn't helpful for anyone seeking help on this problem. If you are going to categorically state "don't use global", at least give a hint at an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple but dirty solution: use a mutable variable.

Instead of

```
currentMovie = 0

def UpdateText():
    currentMovie = random.randint(0, 100)
    print(currentMovie)
```

you can use a single-cell list for currentMovie and pass it as a (default) argument to UpdateText():

```
currentMovie = [0]

def UpdateText(cM=currentMovie): # The default value will 'bind' currentMovie to this argument
    cM[0] = random.randint(0, 100) # This will change the *contents* of the variable
    print(cM[0]) # I used a different name for the parameter to distinguish the two

UpdateText() # Calls UpdateText, updating the contents of currentMovie with a random number
```

Note that setting `currentMovie` itself (not its contents) with a new value—even with a new list—would cause `UpdateText()` to stop updating `currentMovie` unless the `def` block were run again.

```
currentMovie = [0]

def UpdateText(cM=currentMovie): # The default value will 'bind' currentMovie to this argument
    cM[0] = random.randint(0, 100) # This will change the *contents* of the list
    print(cM[0]) # I used a different name for the parameter to distinguish the two

currentMovie = 3 # UpdateText() will no longer affect this variable at all

# This will thus not throw an error, since it's modifying the 'old' currentMovie list:
UpdateText() # The contents of this list can also no longer be accessed
```

This is more of a handy trick if you're building something quick and dirty and don't want to build a class; I find that Python is great for such things, so I think that this is still worthwhile to share despite the other answers.

For more serious purposes, though, creating a class as in [bruno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39894555/12682030) would almost certainly be better.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the already mentioned answers did not work for two reasons.

1. In case of an error, I need the variable for a deeper analysis of the data which led to the error.
2. I'm using the function in a `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` to paste the usual output into a column of the existing DataFrame. Therefore the error information shall not be in the return statement.

**Solution for me:**
Since I did not find a direct solution I decided to write the variable on disk:

```
with open('var.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(var, f)
```

And then to import it where ever I need it:

```
with open('var.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    var = pickle.load(f)
```